# Problems with XSLT and Special Characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xslt, for-xml

On my web app (ASP.net 4,C#) I use FOR XML PATH('') to convert Data from SQL Server to XML,
and use the following lines to feed it to XSLT:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml));
XPathDocument document = new XPathDocument(stream);
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
transform.Load(xsltPath);
transform.Transform(document, null, writer);
return writer.ToString();
```

Now when I feed messages from my forum, in sunny day scenarios, there should be no problem at all and there isn't.
When a user decides to use special characters like < > in their messages thought, there we have the rainy day. 
I get an error which by the way differs from time to time (From message to message depending on what they write there).
I have already tried disable-output-escaping="yes"
Needless to say, I want the users to be able to use some tags like

```
<a href... or <font ...>
```

Below is an example of one of the messages that causes the issue:

```
setting-->about phone----< software update
```

Any possible solutions?

Comment: Use a tool like HTMLTidy to turn the HTML into XHTML -- as a first step, then apply the transformation on the clean result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to *encode* such special characters. As far as XML is concerned, there are 5 of them:

- `>` - `&gt;`
- `<` - `&lt;`
- `&` - `&amp;`
- `"` - `&quot;`
- `'` - `&apos;`

You need to encode these from the use input.

An alternative is to place all user generated content within [`<!\[CDATA\[\]\]>`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) sections, which effectively achieves the same.

Comment: @user1392047 - Either that or use `<![CDATA[]]>`.

Comment: @user1392047 - Around all user generated content. `<![CDATA[some stuff a user created with < & " ' > etc...]]>`